# how to plot the graph based on HashMap data? Java

Tags: java, hashmap, applet, awt

Doing the educational project describes Monte-Carlo simulations of random numbers via some stopping tests.
I have the method which returns HashMap with Integers: keys - numbers, values - quantity of times they met in list.

```
public HashMap<Integer,Integer> predecessorCounter(){

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

    Integer a;

    Predecessor counter = new Predecessor();

    for (Integer i : counter.predecessorList()){
        a = hm.get(i);
        hm.put(i, a == null ? 1 : a + 1);
    }
    return hm;
}
```

Objective: plotting the graph with keys - X, values - Y.
Problem: I have no possibility to use expressions below in main method due to method calling twice, so Keys and Values will be from different Hashmaps as I'm using random incoming data.

```
predecessorCounter().keySet();
predecessorCounter().values();
```

Please, help to solve it:) At least an idea what I need to look at.

Comment: You can use `entrySet()` to get keys and values together, but bear in mind all these methods only return a *view* of the underlying map; they don't capture a snapshot.

Comment: Use a variable Luke.  `map = predecessorCounter(); map.keySet(); map.values();`.   But note that if the map is being changed by another thread, you won't be able to solve the problem like this.